# ValidateUser() fails on IIS but not on Development Server with SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I have an MVC4 project which was upgraded from MVC2. While debugging with the VS development server the user validation works fine. But when I tried to debug with Local IIS the login fails, because of a wrong password.
On the production system the user validation also works fine.
The only difference between the development server / production system and local IIS is, that the website is running in an virtual directory on local IIS. So the URLs are
on development server / production something like:

```
http://localhost:12345/ OR http://the.production.server/
```

but on local IIS it is somthing like:

```
http://localhost/mymvcproject/
```

If I move the website to the root directory on local IIS the login works fine.

In the web.config membership is configured like:

```
<membership>
      <providers>                
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordReset="true" passwordFormat="Encrypted" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="50" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
</membership>
```

I think the problem is the applicationName parameter, but I haven't changed it. 
Things I checked:

- the database data were always the same
- to create and validate an new user does work on local IIS when in virtual directory
- I tested it also with the original MVC2 project, same problem

Am I on the right path?
Is there a way make validation/password encryption/decryption independend from the URL/application name?

Comment: Have you checked the configuration of authentication on IIS side?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich Yes I did, all looks fine. Is there a setting that can cause/solve the problem?

Comment: Have you tried to host it not like virtual folder but just under some port like http://localhost:8878 ?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich That is exactly what the development server does. I update my question.

Comment: If you look at the connection string called `ApplicationServices`, is it available from your live environment?

Comment: @James Yes it is, on live environment everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way make validation/password encryption/decryption
>   independend from the URL/application name?

**No.** Instead, ASP.Net Membership provider uses Machine Key (in addition to salt) to encrypt and decrypt a password.

Normally, you want to include a machine key in application's web.config explicitly to avoid that kind of saturation.

If you know the machine key, save that in Local IIS's web.config explicitly.

If you do not know the machine key, use the following method to retrieve it.

http://aspnetresources.com/blog/how_to_read_auto_generated_machinekey

### Update: 7/9/2013

If you do not assign machine key explicitly, the application will use the auto-generated key by default.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I know the maschine key and it is included in the web.config. If I store it in the IIS web.config does it mean all applications on the IIS use this key? Shouldn't a appliction setting override  the IIS setting?

Comment: If machine key is not in application level web.config, most likely the application is using auto-generated one instead of the one from server level. Please see the updated screen shot which is default setting of IIS.

Comment: I checked it, I did not set the key manually, but the application under root and in the virtual directory hav the same key.

Comment: My first guess will be your application is using auto-generated key (I might be wrong too). At this point, only way to find out is following the link in my answer to retrieve the old key.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. Thanks to @Win, you pushed me to the machine key. Just to make it clear, I know the machine key.
I did not see the little `IsolateApps` parameter in the machine key setting, which is the "key".
With a machine key configured like this:

```
<machineKey validationKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,IsolateApps" decryptionKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,IsolateApps" validation="AES" />
```

I have the behavior like I described in my question. But without the `IsolateApps` like this:

```
<machineKey validationKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" decryptionKey="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" validation="AES" />
```

Everything works fine, no matter if the application is in root or a virtual directory. But there's a catch! I you change the machine like this (not the values, only remove the `IsolateApps` parameter), the user validation fails for existing users. Only new created users can be validated.

The according MSDN page is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100).aspx.